# Como puedo hacer que mi bucle do- while termine al introducir una letra cualquiera?

Tags: java, while

estoy realizando un ejercicio en el que tengo un `do-while` y dentro tengo un scanner en el se introducirán números hasta que se introduzca cualquier letra como puedo hacer el `while`? se me había ocurrido poner algo así como
`while(num!=char)` y que siga preguntando pero da error y no como enfocarlo.

Añado mi código:

```
static ArrayList listadoNumeros = new ArrayList();
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int num = 0;

        do {
            Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);

            try {
            System.out.println("Introduce un numero o una letra: ");
            num = lector.nextInt();
            }
            catch(InputMismatchException e2) {
                System.out.println("No puede introducir letras");
            }

            listadoNumeros.add(num);

        }while("Aqui es donde tengo el problema");
        system.out.println("Frase");
     //metodo que he hecho para iterar el arrayList
}
```

**edit:**

he seguido probando en el código y he colocado esto en el `while`, pero no termina de funcionar

```
}while(Integer.toString(num) != "[0-9]+");
```

Comment: Puedes poner tu codigo por favor para poder tener mas detalles?

Comment: Listo he añadido el codigo :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para hacerlo más fácil podrías crear una variable de tipo `boolean`, en este caso he creado, `esLetra` inicializada en `false`:

```java
boolean esLetra = false;
```

Como ya tienes dentro de un `catch`, la validación si es que se llegara a introducir una letra, se puede poner esa variable dentro y cambiar de `false` a `true`:

```java
static ArrayList listadoNumeros = new ArrayList();
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num = 0;
        boolean esLetra = false;
        do {
            Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);

            try {
                System.out.println("Introduce un numero o una letra: ");
                num = lector.nextInt();
            } catch (InputMismatchException e2) {
                System.out.println("No puede introducir letras");
                esLetra = true; // se cambia su estado
            }

            listadoNumeros.add(num);

        } while (!esLetra); //mientras que esLetra sea falso

        //metodo que he hecho para iterar el arrayList
    }
```

El `while` funciona mientras la variable `esLetra`, sea `false`, es decir `!esLetra`

Entonces, cuando entre al `catch`, además de mandar el mensaje, se cambiará la variable `esLetra` a `true`, dando termino a la iteración.

Comment: justo era eso!!!! Muchisimas gracias!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Espero entender bien su pregunta, para poder hacer lo que requiere, necesitaremos importar las clases **Matcher** y **Pattern** del paquete **regex** de esta forma:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

Como habrá notado, **utilizaremos expresiones regulares** para validarlo, la siguiente expresión que usaremos es: `String expresion = "[0-9]+";` Esto quiere decir que solo aceptaremos números del 0 al 9, el "**+**" se utiliza para permitir más de un caracter.

Finalmente, hacemos el do-while:

```
package practices;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    String entrada = "";
    String expresion = "[0-9]+";

    Matcher mat;

    do {
        System.out.println("Introduzca un número");
        entrada = sc.nextLine().trim(); // Obtenemos el valor de entrada
        Pattern patron = Pattern.compile(expresion); // Añadimos la expresión regular
        mat = patron.matcher(entrada); // Hacemos un "match" entre la entrada y el patron

    } while(mat.matches() || entrada.isEmpty());
    // mat.matches(): Devuelve true si coincide con la expresión regular.

    System.out.println("Fin: No introdujo número");
 }

}
```

Comment: Hola Moises!! Muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda!! mmm deberia ser algo mas sencillo tal vez ya que es para un ejercicio de clase y estos paquetes no los hemos visto en clase

Comment: He estado probando tambien tu codigo al pedir un numero no me termina de funcionar

Comment: Me parece extraño, lo acabo de probar. Para poder darle una mejor respuesta, me podría decir qué métodos le enseñaron y/o qué tema trataron en dicha clase?